# automatic slideshow trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am a very amateur web developer looking to build my first website. Ive handled some html and css, but i have not touched javascript yet. I was looking to make an automatic slideshow for my front page, so i googled some code and found a nice sideshow design here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/ (I should note that i am currently using glitch.com to code on). so i made a .js file since i didnt have one before, and copied the code into their respective files. Everything works except for the javascript, which i kinda suspected would happen. I think im missing some starting code for javascript somewhere, or maybe its outdated with the latest jquery update (the code is from 2013), either way, any help is appreciated

heres the code:

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

```css
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>test area</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="  style.css"> 
  
</head>

  <body>
  
  <div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Comment: You should have to give structure how you had implemented with code !

Comment: I have seen your code from glitch, it's better that you add your code here to understand it better. anyway, I think you missed to include jquery.min.js and add your scripts code in `$( document ).ready` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Jquery but not referencing it.

Similarly like below you have to add

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></sctipt>
```

Cheers

Comment: this may seem dumb, but how did you get that url?

Comment: it's cds URL for jquery i found somewhere from example or blog.